# .htaccess rewrite cond and rule cannot firgure out extra slash at end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been googling around stack overflow trying to figure this out but have had no joy and keep getting errors no matter what I try.

i am currently using this code to rewrite the address to remove extensions, I got it from a SO post a while ago for simple websites:

```
RewriteEngine on

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.phtml [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.phtml -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.phtml [L]
```

(i use phtml files as ui files and php for background files, hence the second block)

This works fine for me but now i am on a site where i would like to feed get variables to a page for bookmarking etc and do not want the address to be some thing like `www.website.com/page?var=0`

i have managed to get my testing site to load `www.website.com/page/` using code from another SO post, but only if i enter that url, it will not rewrite if i go to page.html and will not load the attached files css, js (i understand this is because the files have a relative path) **Edit:** I now understand this is to do with -f || !-f;
code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I am fine with either having or not having a trailing slash, but I do want to add it when there are variables, like `page?var=0` to `page/var=0` without the images, js and css stopping. of course if it can all be with a slash then all the better.

Thanks

**Edit:** Also needs to work when the website and .htaccess are in a subfolder, like: mysite.com/example/websitedemonstration/page

Comment: if you use QSA flag you won't have problems with the query string, for example `[QSA,L]` or `[R=301,QSA,L]` etc. QSA will append the query string to the next URL so it would keep the `?var=0` as is if u don't like the ending backslash then you better of off removing it from `/$1/` to `/$1` and adding an `?` to `/?$`

Comment: hey, thanks for help. I do want the ending backslash but it does not work correctly. i'm nearly there, i can externally redirect to `/page/` but internally cannot then point to the file! I am using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f` newline 
`RewriteRule ^/ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one seems to work fine for me, give it a try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.(html|phtml) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.html [L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.phtml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.phtml -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.phtml [L]
```

Comment: This works fine if I remove rewrite base and type www..../page - and loads without relative images css etc if i type www..../page/ - but gives an error if I add a variable /page.html?var=a.  i have just found that if i want the trailing slash on standard page with no variables i need to update all links and attached files with a prepending `../` Edit: can i ask what `([^/]*)` does

Comment: OK it is nearly there, the code works for everything except adding a slash between the page and the variable! example: `page.html?var=a` becomes `page?var=a`, is it possible to make it `page/?var=a` Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @slappy-x on your first rule, use %1/ and it will append the ? if it had one.